# How do I opt-out of privacy sensitive redaction for locked device?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

I can't seem to make my watch WidgetKit complication to show while the device is locked. This is done in the weather complication and can be seen if you take off your watch and set it down, but my widget is redacted until unlocked.

I tried adding `.unredacted` to my root widget view but same behaviour. Is this something I can do from the app code or is this only controlled by the user? I don't remember setting this on the weather complication so I thought it set itself as public which is what I would like to do. It is not clear how to achieve this [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchOS-Apps/designing-your-app-for-the-always-on-state).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a hint to the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653642/1987726). Since I did not completely understand it, I tried some ideas and found a working solution for a single widget. An extension to multiple widgets in a widget family should work accordingly.

```
@main
struct ShopEasy_Widgets: Widget {
    let kind: String = "ShopEasy__WidgetKit_Extension"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            ShopEasy_WidgetKitsEntryView(entry: entry)
                .unredacted()
        }
        .supportedFamilies([.accessoryCircular, .accessoryInline, .accessoryRectangular, .accessoryCorner])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, that worked! The key for me was putting it in the `WidgetConfiguration` and for all complications.

Comment: just a note about this, this shows the placeholder data not the timeline one.

Comment: This finally got the View showing when I pick widgets on the watch. Still shows blank when the watch is locked ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Did you already implement WKSupportsAlwaysOnDisplay? If not, ensure that you have done so. I believe it takes a boolean value. If you have already done so, I have seen that specifying whether or not each section of your complication as either .unreadacted or .redacted can help to solve this issue.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/wksupportsalwaysondisplay) say: _Apps compiled for watchOS 8 and later have Always On enabled by default_