# WatchOS Complication Flashing

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos, widgetkit

I am making a very simple WidgetKit complication and unfortunately it flashes every time the watch face awakens. My Apple Watch is up to date with WatchOS 9.4. I experienced this before but seemed to fix the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the watch app. Unfortunately, that is not proving successful anymore. Does anyone have any ideas? Here is my code. You can assume `getCount()` returns 0 immediately - replacing it with this does not stop the flashing.

```
//
//  DrinkCountComplications.swift
//  DrinkCountComplications
//
//  Created by Bryce Sandlund on 11/6/22.
//

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), count: getCount())
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), count: getCount())
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        completion(Timeline(entries: [SimpleEntry(date: Date(), count: getCount())], policy: TimelineReloadPolicy.never))
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let count: Int
}

struct DrinkCountComplicationsEntryView : View {
    var entry: SimpleEntry

    var body: some View {
        let link = URL(string: "myApp://widgetClick")?
            .appending(queryItems: [URLQueryItem(name: "count", value: String(entry.count))])
        ZStack {
            Text("DRINK")
                .offset(x: 0, y: -15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
            Text(String(entry.count))
                .font(.title)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
            Text("COUNT")
                .offset(x: 0, y: 15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
        }
        .unredacted()
        .widgetURL(link)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background()
    }
}

@main
struct DrinkCountComplications: Widget {
    let kind: String = "DrinkCountComplications"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            DrinkCountComplicationsEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Drink Count Widget")
        .description("Display drink count & add a drink")
    }
}

struct DrinkCountComplications_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DrinkCountComplicationsEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), count: getCount()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .accessoryRectangular))
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been having the same issue — for me, it was a clear regression with either watchOS 9.3 or 9.4, can't remember. For me it will even occasionally show wrong views after flashing (e.g., I differentiate views based on `widgetRenderingMode`, and my accented view will randomly be shown with a full-color watch face). If I disable the always-on setting of the watch display, it goes away, so I think it has to do with how WidgetKit is dealing with `isLuminanceReduced` but I haven't found a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to isolate this in my app and then reproduce it in an example project. I can't guarantee this is going to be the only possible cause — especially since it makes zero sense!

For me, the cause was using the `.widgetURL(_)` modifier on the view returned by my widget `View`:

```swift
struct RedrawWidgetsEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Capsule()
            .fill(.white)
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity)
            .widgetURL(URL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
    }
}
```

I tried a variety of things, and numerous issues cropped up. The workaround I have arrived at that seems to be holding up is to move the widgetURL to an off-screen view, and I turned it into a modifier.

```swift
@available(watchOS 9, *)
fileprivate struct WidgetURLWatchWorkaround: ViewModifier {
    let url: URL
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background {
                Color.white
                    .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                    .position(x: -1000, y: -1000)
                    .widgetURL(url)
            }
    }
}

@available(watchOS 9, *)
extension View {
    func widgetURLWatch(_ url: URL) -> some View {
        modifier(WidgetURLWatchWorkaround(url: url))
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Swapped out `EmptyView()` for `Color.black`, because while it works in the sim, on-device I guess that it (as well as `Color.clear`) get optimized out.

Edit 2: Updated with a newer workaround due to issues with previous one.

Comment: It does seem the `.widgetURL()` modifier has an impact on the flash. Removing it makes the flash much shorter and less noticeable, but it does not remove it entirely (for me). I'm beginning to think the root cause is likely something related to how much time it takes iOS to populate the view. I wonder if there is a different reason / strategy altogether that can be used to remove the flashing entirely.

Comment: When you said flash, is it 1 time flash or continuing flashing? I notice that sometimes when the watch wakes up my widgets kinda flash once and gets bigger. I mean I can easily see that the widget view is off for split second. In contrast, on Apple's own widgets, they smoothly gets bigger when watch wake up.

Comment: It is a one time flash. My experience is the same as yours - the Apple widgets get slightly bigger with no flash, but my widget gets bigger and flashes. The flash is way more pronounced with the .widgetURL modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I tracked it down to a call to `.privacySensitive(false)`.

I was incorrectly using that to make sure that my widget continued to show when the device was locked. Commenting out that line stopped the widget from flashing/refreshing when the screen woke up.

What I should have been doing was calling `.unredacted()` on my widget's view. As mentioned in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/unredacted()). (Although tbh I found it via [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130077/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privacy-sensitive-redaction-for-locked-device)!)

Comment: This is interesting. For me I need to use both .privacySensitive() and .unredacted(). If I understand correctly privacySensitive is used with watch lock state. while unredacted is used with watch low luminance.

Comment: I thought this fixed the problem for me but it does not fix it on real watch. The problem is related `.widgetURL` and the other answer solves it